# Calculating Probabilities: Picking matching shoes!

Tags: probability

The question I am trying to tackle is this,

A box contains 10 pairs of shoes (20 shoes in total). If two shoes are selected at random, what is the probability that they are matching shoes?

My attempt at solving this goes this way, I would like someone to tell me why my reasoning is wrong.

Reformulating the problem, let's say there are  10 A and 10 B, totaling 20 items in a bag. Now, we pick two items randomly, we would like to know the probability of picking two items so that if first one is A, then second one is B, or if first one is B then the second one is A. Please correct me if I am wrong in this formulation.

If the formulation is correct, then I think the probability calculation should go in the following way,

If the first picked item is A, then the probability of picking B as the second item is,  (10/20) * (10/19)

If the first picked item is B, then the probability of the picking A as the second item is, (10/20) * (10/19)

So in total,   2 * (10/20) * (10/ 19)  = 10/19

Calculating the same thing in a flipped way:

Probability of picking A twice =  (10/20) * (9/19)
Probability of picking B twice = (10/20) * (9/ 19)
So,  Probability of picking two different things = 1 - 9/19 or 10/19

Or am I wrong in calculating this?

The answer bank says the result should be 1/19...

Comment: You first pick a shoe. What is the chance that the next one you select will match that shoe?

Comment: It makes sense what you are saying, but what's wrong in my calculation, can you share that? Hmmm. I got it, in the question, they meant that all shoe pairs are different, I thought the shoes are all same kind. :3

Comment: Updated it, thanks, @RossMillikan